# ethers.js web version, but not hardhat local version, gives error when calling contract

Tags: ethers.js, struct, hardhat

In a react/ethers web page connected to Polygon Mumbai, I get this classic error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address or ENS name
> (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT,
> version=contracts/5.5.0)

when calling

```
const factory = new ethers.Contract("0xb4aF5bdB5E4d5e0b079920A5C83082348DC529e5", abis['BeaconProxyFactory'], signer);
await factory.createBookBeaconProxy({
    "owner": "0xC8834C1FcF0Df6623Fc8C8eD25064A4148D99388",
    "name": "example_name",
    "symbol": "example_symbol",
    "supply": 1000000,
    "price": {
        "type": "BigNumber",
        "hex": "0x8ac7230489e80000"
    },
    "priceToken": "0x35935060E9160a8815312a2c2586109e8C10AD86",
    "resaleEnabled": false,
    "category": "Comic Book",
    "description": "example description",
    "initialVersionHash": "1fcdf69cdbb461aec07737b15b87ae16091b51a4ed1ea8b9b3a786948c77d4f1",
    "initialVersionURI": "QmbfSRwp4t7e2e6shULedb9rANGKsv7c1BCkmtVvYFxKkw"
});
```

However, I don't get it in a hardhat local environment. My test scripts which call that function run just fine with hardhat when Mumbai is forked as well.

This code in ethers.js also worked before I refactored my code to take a struct as an argument. But it seems ethers and hardhat both have the same syntax for structs, so perhaps this error was from something else which changed...

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, ethers.js and hardhat use different syntax when passing structs as arguments. Changing the argument to createBookBeaconProxy to

```
["0xC8834C1FcF0Df6623Fc8C8eD25064A4148D99388", "example_name", "example_symbol", 1000000, 14, "0x35935060E9160a8815312a2c2586109e8C10AD86", false, "Coming-of-age", "example desriptipn", "1fcdf69cdbb461aec07737b15b87ae16091b51a4ed1ea8b9b3a786948c77d4f1", "QmbfSRwp4t7e2e6shULedb9rANGKsv7c1BCkmtVvYFxKkw"]
```

fixed this issue.